Can the current file ID be obtained by a Google Workspace Addon without document-specific authorization?
On the Event Objects page of the Google developer documentation, it says that the current file's ID will only be present when the auth/drive.file scope is authorized for the current file. In all other circumstances, however, auth/drive seems to provide the same access as auth/drive.file (With the file ID, it can perform all of the same api calls), but without approving access to files individually.
Is there another way to get the ID, and if not, is there an explanation for why auth/drive is insufficient?

The problem with using auth/drive is that its too permissive. It's designated as a restricted scope. Any add-on with a restricted scope will trigger a security assessment during the verification process and you may end up paying hundreds or thousands of dollars in annual fees.

Yes, it's possible.
The /oauth/drive scope gives the same permissions than /oauth/drive.file and a lot more.
Please bear in mind that the first will make the publication of the add-on as public more cumberstome due to the required approval process.
Reference

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

